# OCR Computing Question

Tags: ocr

I was asked the below question in a test at school last week and I thought the answer given was incorrect.

You had to give a file format from the options for the below statement:

A file created in software that most users will not have available

You had two options, PDF or DOCX. I answered DOCX but apparently the answer was PDF, what do you think?

Comment: This isn't really the perfect site for this question, though I'm not sure which other site on the network is a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an advertisement for Microsoft...

The intention was that while DOCX can be created using the rather expensive but commonly available Microsoft Word, PDF is created by Adobe Acrobat (not the free Reader!) which is not commonly available. However, there are many other ways to create PDFs, and nowadays you can print to PDF even on Windows, which is roughly as commonly available as Microsoft Word.

In conclusion, it's an oversight by the question setters, who appear to be parroting material which has been influenced by Microsoft for obvious commercial purposes.